# nslookup fails but PowerShell's resolve-dnsname works

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

This is not a domain I have anything to do with, but I don't understand what's going on. The nameservers for sciencedaily.com are:

- ns-1414.awsdns-48.org.
- ns-1618.awsdns-10.co.uk.
- ns-300.awsdns-37.com.
- ns-695.awsdns-22.net.

If I run nslookup and type `server ns-1414.awsdns-48.org` and then `sciencedaily.com` it returns

`*** ns-1414.awsdns-48.org can't find sciencedaily.com: No response from server`

But it I run `resolve-dnsname sciencedaily.com -server ns-1414.awsdns-48.org` in PowerShell it returns the DNS records correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `server ns-1414.awsdns-48.org` is prefering IPv6 over IPv4 due to IPv6 being enabled on the network interface; and it makes nslookup stick with IPv6 for the following request(s). Due to a missing IPv6 connection to the outside world however, that DNS request fails. It seems it works when calling nslookup like `nslookup sciencedaily.com ns-1414.awsdns-48.org` and as you said when using resolve-dnsname. Usage of IPv6 for the DNS request can also be avoided by looking up the IP(v4) of `ns-1414.awsdns-48.org` first and do

```
$ nslookup
> server 205.251.19
> sciencedaily.com
```